# Authentication problems

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to automate the process to create a model with azure machine learning services and I get some problems with the authentication. When I run my code on my remote machine everything is fine but when I run the code on remote I get this authentication sentence:

```
Make sure your code doesn't require 'az login' to have happened before using azureml-SDK, except the case when you are specifying AzureCliAuthentication in azureml-SDK.
Performing interactive authentication. Please follow the instructions on the terminal.
To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code CZMKCYS8B to authenticate"
```

Azure ask me for authentication and I have to make it manually.
I would like to know if there is some way to do it automatically.

I was looking for it and I was investigated how to do it using tokens but I couldn't find any solution

Someone can give me an advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The warning was added in one of the latest updates of the SDK. If you don't see it on you own machine, I assume you haven't updated the SDK to the latest version? I am curious myself on how to configure the login so that the message doesn't appear, so I hope someone can answer that four you.

Comment: Hello, thanks for you answer. 
I found this jupyter notebook with the solution:
https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/manage-azureml-service/authentication-in-azureml/authentication-in-azure-ml.ipynb


I used the method Service Principal Authentication as I saw in that tutorial and its working fine.

Comment: Sweet. I have been looking (not very hard) for such a guide.